# Confusion on TF2 frame name conventions, base_link vs odom?

Tags: ros2, tf2, coordinate-system, transformations

I was reading about TF2 frame name conventions for mobile robots:

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

and I'm confused on how base_link and odom frames are related, odom gives the location of the robot in world frame, but what defines the transformation between odom and base_link? It seems like they should be the same.

Comment: I think will answer your question, see my answer to the original question:   https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104830/correct-use-of-transformations-while-using-coordinate-frames/104853#104853

Answer (score 2):

The `odom -> base_link` transform is published by the odometry system of your robot (from wheel encoders, IMU, etc.). on the other hand, your navigation system is supposed to publish the `map -> base_link` transform, however, because a frame can´t have more than one parent this transform is published as `map -> odom`.

Comment: I'm still confused, what does the odometery frame represent then if not the robots location?

Comment: The transform from the odom -> base_link represents the motion of the vehicle since it started based on the odometer. Odometry drifts over time. So the localization calculates the position of the robot in the map. But instead of publishing that, it computes the origin of the odom frame and published that. Which is effectively correcting for drift in the odometry over time as well as the initial position.

Comment: I'm still confused, I understand that odom is supposed to represent the uncorrected odometery(IE no loop closure?) but how does its origin get updated?

Comment: Also it seems literally every update will cause a small time jump, even doing windowed smoothing would cause it. So for odom would actually calculates it? Is it only motion model?

Answer (score -1):

Odom and base_link are physically attached, since your base_link is usually robot's chassis and the odometry is fixed over it. They are moving together. But in Robotics everything is joint and link, so a link (base_link) must be parent of other link (odom_link). The odometry is just needed to be attached to base_link because it provides odometry data (displacement from map origin) and can be fused to IMU or/and GPS, or/and Lidar data to improve your localization System.

That is the whole picture.